# How to instantiate a class(ClassA) inside another class(ClassB) and use the ClassA object as a property in ClassB in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function Coord(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Ellipse() {
    this.Text = Text;
    this.Cx = Cx;
    this.Cy = Cy;
    this.Rx = Rx;
    this.Ry = Ry;
}
```

Now in the function `Ellipse`instead of using `Cx`, `Cy` etc. I want to instantiate the function `Coord` for each pair to achieve something as follows:

```
function Coord(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Ellipse() {
    this.Text = Text;
    Coord C = new C(); // where C has its own properties x and y
    Coord R = new R(); // where R has its own properties x and y
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Coord(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function Ellipse(text, cx, cy, rx, ry) {
    this.text = text;
    var c = new Coord(cx, cy);
    var r = new Coord(rx, ry);
}
```

I don't know how you thought of `Coord C = new C()` but it's absolutely wrong. JavaScript variables have no types.

Also from where are you getting `Text`, `Cx`, `Cy`, etc? Shouldn't they be passed as arguments to the constructor?